# Compute engine to app engine queuing system changes in php project

Tags: google-app-engine, google-cloud-platform, rabbitmq, google-cloud-tasks

Our project was running in GCP compute engine. For scaling purpose, it is moved to app engine. We had rabbitmq implemented for push messages and chatbots in compute engine. In app engine it is not feasible to implement rabbitmq. So I was going through alternate options. There I found cloud task option. But I have doubts in certain areas even after reading their documentation

1. In my understanding, we need an app engine instance for cloud tasks. In that case, can I implement it in same project itself as a different service? Will this affect the performance of the existing project?
2. Is there any better solution than cloud tasks in this case?

Answer (score 0):

1. You can implement additional services under your app in the App Engine as shown in this [diagram](https://cloud.google.com/appengine/docs/standard/nodejs/an-overview-of-app-engine#components_of_an_application).

> By default, App Engine scales your app to match the load. Your apps will scale up the number of instances that are running to provide consistent performance, or scale down to minimize idle instances and reduces costs.

2. You can consider running a RabbitMQ Cluster on Google Kubernetes Engine. You can find more information in the following documentation: [rabbitmq](https://github.com/GoogleCloudPlatform/click-to-deploy/blob/master/k8s/rabbitmq/README.md).